# Books of differential geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Teaching myself differential topology and differential geometry.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13575/teaching-myself-differential-topology-and-differential-geometry)

Dear all,

I really need some reference books about differential geometry.
Recently I am taking a course of representation theory and symmetry method for DE. I feel too difficult to read the materials without the knowledge of differential geometry.

I would like to have a reference book on elementary level treating manifolds relevant to differential equations. And it's better with some concrete examples.

Thank you very much.

Cheers,
Jan

Comment: Please have a look at this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13575/teaching-myself-differential-topology-and-differential-geometry

Comment: ...and this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17969/differential-geometry-of-curves-and-surfaces-bibliography

Comment: Dear newbie, please see the (very similar) questions posted in the comments, where numerous answers have been posted.