# Book about elementary geometry , triangles, circles ...

Tags: reference-request, big-list

Currently, I'm studying a little about geometry and I was trying to find out some good book about it on internet, however I didn't find anything that I thought nice to me or what I really expected to which would be nice. What I'm looking for is a book with good proofs, in which show strategies to you reach the solution. and interesting exercises.

For instance :

[GoGeometry 1](http://gogeometry.com/school-college/p859-triangle-angle-45-18-degrees-congruence.htm)
, [GoGeometry 2](http://gogeometry.com/problem/p753-triangle-altitude-orthocenter-ratio-high-school-college.htm), [GoGemetry 3](http://gogeometry.com/problem/p741-triangle-incenter-circumcircle-midpoint-arc-chord-congruence.htm) ...

Something about mostly elementary geometry, proprieties of triangles, parallels lines, circles, triangle inscribed in a circle, so on.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107882/geometry-book-recommendation?rq=1, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34442/book-recommendation-on-plane-euclidean-geometry?rq=1, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264331/recommending-books-for-intro-to-diff-geometry?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

You can check this [geometry](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387986502) book written by Hartshorne

I haven't read this book yet, but I guess it would be great.

Comment: please provide free books if possible